# When does React Native select platform-specific code, compiling or running?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

### Case 1:

```
const MyComponent = () => Platform.select({
  ios: <MyComponentIos>,
  android: <MyComponentAndroid>,
});
```

In this case, I guess that React Native gets platform info and selects components dynamically in running. But how about the next case:

### Case 2:

`MyComponent.android.jsx`:

```
// ...
export default MyComponentAndroid;
```

`MyComponent.ios.jsx`:

```
// ...
export default MyComponentIos;
```

`App.jsx`:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
```

Does React Native choose the correct module in running?

Or in compiling(at least like it should not bundle the `.android.jsx` file into an ios build)?

And why?

Comment: whatever bundler you are using will decide which file to bundle for Android and for IOS. It basically creates a dependency graph at build time only.